# How to publish html reports in azure pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to take up other reports like extent report in selenium needs to be taken into azure pipelines to see the different results than azure default one.

Comment: Present your code that you have already tried to reach a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Publishing html report in Azure pipelines which is not support at present. There has been a related user voice:

> **Support for generic HTML Publishing inside Build and Release Pipelines**
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/491426/support-for-generic-html-publishing-inside-build-a.html

You could vote up it and our PM will kindly review it. In other words, html reports for selenium automation test could not view inline as a web page at the moment.  As a workaround, you have to download the html report files locally and check it.